# Angular ui-router fails to resolve named dependencies

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

I recently migrated from ui-router 0.0.1 to 0.2.0. Since the migration, ui-router fails to resolve named dependencies that needs to be injected into a view's controller. Here's the sample code which works fine with ver 0.0.1 but fails in ver 0.2.0

```
angular.module( 'sample.test', [
 'ui.router',
 'i18nService'
])

.config(function config($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state( 'mystate', {
      url: '/mystate',
      resolve: {i18n: 'i18nService'},
      views: {
        'main': {
          controller: 'MyCtrl',
          templateUrl: 'templates/my.tpl.html'
        }
      }
    });
})

.controller('MyCtrl', ['i18n', function(i18n) {
   // fails to resolve i18n
}]);
```

i18nService is a simple service that return a promise

```
angular.module('i18nService', [])
.factory('i18nService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  $http.get('..').then(..);

  return deferred.promise;
}]);
```

I get the error "Unknown provider: i18nProvider <- i18n" when using v0.2.0

If i change the resolve config to:

```
      resolve: {
        i18n: function(i18nService) {
          return i18nService
        }
      },
```

everything works fine. Is this an expected behaviour, or am I missing some configuration?

Here's the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/johqGn1CgefDVKGzIt6q?p=preview

Comment: could you create a plunkr that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: @dtabuenc I've updated the plunkr, please have a look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug that was fixed last month:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/commit/4cdadcf46875698aee6c3684cc32f2a0ce553c45

I don't believe it's in any currently released version, but you could either get the latest from github or make the change yourself in your js file. It's simply changing key to value in that one line (you can see it in the github commit).

A workarround is to just not change the name for now.... do

```
resolve :{
  i18nService: 'i18nService'
}
```

Then inject `i18nService` to your controller instead of i18n. It's a bit of a hack, but it does work (it injects the resolved service not the promise).

Comment: I've seen another issue using your approach - the dependency gets resolved twice - once in resolve and once when instantiating the controller.

Comment: Yeah, I was surprised it even worked at all when I tested it.